# Swift how to show rating value in star rating

Tags: swift, uiview, cocoapods, rating

I am trying to show the average rating value in the HCSStarRatingView from cocoa pods. I have a method that figures out the average and now i want pass the average Double to display the correct star rating in Todays Rating. I was wondering how can i do this?
[Todays Star Rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAjSe.png)

Here is the rating average

```
  class RatingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
var dateValue = Date()
var pastRating: Double = 0.0
@IBInspectable weak var rating: HCSStarRatingView!

var review: Workout?{
    didSet{
        configureCell()
    }
}
func configureCell(){
    if let review = review{
        review.appointment?.scheduled = dateValue
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "mm-dd-YYYY"
        let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: dateValue)
        dateLabel.text = formattedDate
        pastRating = 0.0
    }
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

and here is the table view

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
        fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
    }
    return sections.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let dequeuedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RatingTableViewCell", for: indexPath);
        guard let cell = dequeuedCell as? RatingTableViewCell else {
            return dequeuedCell
    }
    cell.review = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of you code.So that i can have look into it

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore i edited the post

Comment: @MattBrown, Can you share code of cellForRow method ?

Comment: @PaulMarshal i updated the post and added the cellForRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen **HCSStarRatingView**, there are property given to display accurate rating. So change you code:

```
if let review = review{
    review.appointment?.scheduled = dateValue
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "mm-dd-YYYY"
    let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: dateValue)
    dateLabel.text = formattedDate

    // You need to change code like this.
    rating.accurateHalfStars = true
    rating.value = <YourAverageRating>

    pastRating = 0.0    // I don't know about this, So can maintain it.
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: How do i change it from double to CGFloat?

Comment: @MattBrown, It simple, just write following line of code CGFloat(<YourDoubleValue>).

Comment: @MattBrown, If this answer work for you then accept it, So it's helpful to other user who will use HCSStarRatingView.